# Google Drive viewer not showing a pdf at Angular app

Tags: angular, pdf-generation

I have an iFrame at my Angular app view in order to show a pdf file. I use "https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=my.pdf" for the purpose. And the issue is that sometimes it shows my pdf but sometimes it does not.

So how do I have it stable?

Comment: I don´t understand your question. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - with this in mind you´ll be able to ask a question which will be answered from the community.

Comment: Looks like you're not an Angular developer. That's why you don't understand it. Sorry for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one : ng2-pdf-viewer
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer

Comment: I'm getting CORS issue when using ng2-pdf-viewer. Did you face same issue?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you figure out how to fix it? Thanks in advance.